# très froid ... why the "s"?

Tags: liaisons

I got a "word of the day" from a website where I subscribe.  It was 'froid'.  The sentence included "très froid".  When I listened to the native speaker say the sentence, I heard not "tray frwah" (sorry for the unofficial pronunciation attempt) that I would have expected, but "trays frwah".

I understand that due to liaisons, one puts the consonant "back" before vowels.  Why is it back in this case?

Thanks, Janet 
(B1 ranking -- which means I have a LOT to learn.  Any help appreciated.)

Comment: Simply put, consonants remove the aspect of "liaisons". Therefor, you don't prononce the S in *Très* in that case. Although, in something like "Très aimé" you will have a "liaison" and will pronounce the S (will sound like Z) in *Très*.

Comment: Is it [this site](http://www.transparent.com/word-of-the-day/today/french.html)? I can see how one could easily hear an "s" there, but I think it's really just the "f".

Comment: Yes, that's the site, and you could be right.  "s" and "f" (like 50 and 60, in english) are problems for me so I could just be hearing things.  Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 6):

The 'S' here isn't pronounced. What you are hearing is the beginning of the 'f' (or maybe some audio glitches).

Answer (score -1):

The **s** of *très* is silent. Pretend like you are saying tre froid. Remember the CaReFuL rule. If a French word ends in C, R, F or L (the letters in CaReFuL), the final letter is pronounced. The **s** in *très* is silent since it does not follow the rule. Of course there are exceptions just like other rules that also have exceptions.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Eh, never heard of that rule before. Clever.

Comment: Where does this rule come from? We never pronounce the final **C** in *accroc* neither the final **L** in *fusil*

Comment: R is almost never pronounced in words ending in -er...

Comment: Some exceptions: croc, cerf, fusil, and all verbs ending with 'er'